# Converting Chrome Page Action -> Browser Action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Page Action extension in production. Now, I would like to convert it to a Browser Action extension.

I have changed my manifest.json and everything seems to be working fine. Will this change be as smooth for my users when they update? Should I expect something else to happen for my users?

Answer (score 2):

Probably, your users will not notice the update, I guess. Because, In the latest Chrome version, all page actions are put on the  same place as all browser actions.

Comment: Yeah, that was a really strange move. I mean doing it without telling developers in advance.Thanks!